# Restful URLs design modeling forum groups and posts

Tags: url, rest, restful-url

Is my design on modeling forum group and post good enough?

1. Group URL
   http://www.example.com/groups/soccer
2. Post URL
   http://www.example.com/groups/soccer/posts/123.html

Any better suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks fine to me. Drop the '.html' to have all the cool kids say, "ooo, now it even *looks* RESTful". ;)